# Why page_action couldn't appear on pop-up windows?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I'm making a chrome extension and using page_action instead of browser_action because I need this extension for only one specific url. I'm using declerativeContent for activating the page_action;

```
// When the extension is installed or upgraded ...
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  // Replace all rules ...
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    // With a new rule ...
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
      {
        // That fires when a page's URL contains ...
        conditions: [
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { hostEquals: 'www.example.com', schemes: ['https'] },
          })
        ],
        // And shows the extension's page action.
        actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
      }
    ]);
  });
});
```

In normal tabs of chrome, there is no problem. Page_action works exactly the way I want. But in pop-up windows, there is a problem. I mean, there is page that contains links to pop-up pages. When I click to them, pop-up windows open but I can't see the page_actions in the address bar.

What could be the problem?

Comment: I don't think Chrome supports page actions on popups.

Comment: Are you sure? I mean, I haven't seen any page action that works on popups or I haven't seen a document contains that page actions don't work on popup, either.  But is there a way to do it, I'd like to implement for my extension. Or can you advice a documentation that suppors your idea, I can give up.

Comment: I installed two page_action extensions and neither icons were displayed in a popup. I would guess this is an explicit decision by Google but you can file a [feature request](http://crbug.com/new) to try and get it changed.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Google Chrome extensions doesn't provide page_action icon on the adress bar in pop-up windows. But still, extension works on that window. You should think other ways to make your extension functional.